# Request scopes with GoogleSignInOptions for Tasks API

Tags: android, api, task, google-signin, google-tasks-api

I've achieved to set up a Google Sign In in my Android application. According to Google Developers, requesting the scope for an API should be as easy as:

```
if (!GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(
        GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getActivity()),
        TasksScopes.TASKS)) {
    GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
            MyExampleActivity.this,
            RC_REQUEST_PERMISSION_SUCCESS_CONTINUE_FILE_CREATION,
            GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getActivity()),
            TasksScopes.TASKS);
} else {
    saveToDriveAppFolder();
}
```

> "...call GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions to launch an activity that requests the additional required scopes from the user." https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/additional-scopes

or

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .requestScopes(TasksScopes.TASKS)
                .build();
```

> If you need to request additional scopes to access Google APIs,
>   specify them with requestScopes https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/additional-scopes

However, with [Tasks API](https://developers.google.com/tasks/auth), the error "requestScopes in Builder cannot be applies to java.lang.String" appears.

I've also tried to replicate this [sample piece of code](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/tree/master/tasks-android-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/tasks/android)

P.S. The rest of Google Sign-in funtionality works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was so simple...

'Scope scope = new Scope("scopeurl")'

Scope url comes from Google Developers Oauth [Scopes page](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes).